# inserting sequence with sqloader

Tags: oracle, sequence

I have a weird problem with sqloader..In my database I created a sequence like this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE TEST_ID_SEQ
  MINVALUE 1
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
  CACHE 20;
```

And my control-file looks like this:

```
load data
INFILE 'C:\Users\\test.csv'
into table TABLE_NAME
append
fields terminated by ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' AND '"'
trailing nullcols
           (
             TEST_COLUMN_ID "TEST_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL",
             INSERT_DATE EXPRESSION "current_timestamp(3)",
             COLUMN_1 CHAR(4000),   
             COLUMN_2 CHAR(4000),   
              ......
           )
```

So during the import I just want to insert a generated  number in the column "TEST_COLUMN_ID".

The problem now is that if i write this line in my control-file:

```
                 TEST_COLUMN_ID "TEST_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL",
```

then the wother values wont be imported correctly. Which means, all the values will be shifted to the right. For example the content of the value in COLUMN_1 will be imported in COLUMN_2 and so on..when i delete the line than it works correctly.....can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok the solution is to put the SEQ_NUMBER field as the last field in the control
file. If someone is interested he can see this link for more details: http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/377/Oracle/SQL-loader/FAQ.html